# Aurelia: data binding issue with the primary property of a custom attribute

Tags: typescript, data-binding, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I am learning about Aurelia for a few weeks now and I seem to have a data binding issue with a custom attribute.

I have created the following `square` custom attribute (based on the examples from the ["Templating:Custom Attributes" guide on the Aurelia website](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-attributes)):

**square.ts:**

```ts
import { bindable, autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject
export class SquareCustomAttribute {
  @bindable sideLength = "100px";
  @bindable color = "red";

  constructor(private element: Element) {
    this.sideLengthChanged(this.sideLength);
    this.colorChanged(this.color);
  }

  sideLengthChanged(newValue: string) {
    if (this.element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = newValue;
    }
  }

  colorChanged(newValue: string) {
    if (this.element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like this custom attribute to be usable without explicitly binding it, in which case it should use the default values, like in this consuming view:

**app.html:**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./square"></require>
  <div square></div>
</template>
```

The code above works fine. It renders the `div` as a square with 100px sides and a red background.

Problems arise when I set the `color` property of `SquareCustomAttribute` as the primary property (using `@bindable`'s configuration object parameter) like this:

**Updated square.ts:**

```ts
import { bindable, autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject
export class SquareCustomAttribute {
  @bindable sideLength = "100px";
  @bindable({ primaryProperty: true }) color = "red";

  constructor(private element: Element) {
    this.sideLengthChanged(this.sideLength);
    this.colorChanged(this.color);
  }

  sideLengthChanged(newValue: string) {
    if (this.element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = newValue;
    }
  }

  colorChanged(newValue: string) {
    if (this.element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, setting `color` as the primary property of the custom attribute, the `colorChanged` callback gets invoked twice now: first by the constructor with the default value and then once more from somewhere in the lifecycle initialization with an empty value.

How can I avoid this second invocation of the `colorChanged` callback, so that the default value of the primary property of my custom attribute will not be cleared when I do not explicitly supply a binding/value of the `square` attribute in the consuming view's HTML markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to tackle this another way:

```
import { bindable, autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject
export class SquareCustomAttribute {
  @bindable sideLength;
  @bindable({ primaryProperty: true }) color;

  constructor(private element: Element) {
  }

  sideLengthChanged(newValue: string) {
    if (this.element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = newValue;
    }
  }
  
  bind(){
    this.sideLengthChanged(this.sideLength ? this.sideLength : "100px");
    this.colorChanged(this.color ? this.color : "red");
  }

  colorChanged(newValue: string) {
    if (this.element instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

When you declare `{ primaryProperty: true }`, you are basically telling the framework to create a binding on the value of your custom attribute, whether it is filled or not, the framework will map it to your color property.
so when you declare `<div square></div>`, the color property in the `bind()` lifecycle will be an empty string.
As `bind()` is only invoked once, it's the perfect spot to declare your default values, should they be empty in the beginning.

Example here: https://gist.dumber.app/?gist=b0244ac4078e2a0664b7be0fbcc0b22b

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) This indeed seems to be the most elegant solution. I did have to make some minor adjustments to your solution code due to my stricter TypeScript configuration, but it works perfectly. I hoped that the `bind` method could be avoided even here, but in production code I would probably need an `unbind` method as well for cleaning up the styling. I must say that after posting my question, I was in doubt if my scenario was somewhat too exotic. When a custom attribute's logic becomes so complex, I would also start thinking about migrating it to a custom element instead.